# R markdown hangs, but all code chunks work

Tags: r-markdown

R markdown gets stuck on chunk 1, which is repeated below:

````
---
title: "RMark1"  
author: "df"  
date: "11/19/2017"  
output:  
  html_document:  
    toc: true  
---

```{r setup}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(readr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
print("loaded libraries")
```
````

**what am I missing here?**

Comment: Works fine on my machine ... can't reproduce your error